# Azure VirtualNetworkGatewayConnection has no ConnectionStatus for ExpressRoute ConnectionType

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-virtual-network

We try to extract **ConnectionStatus** for Azure VirtualNetworkGateway.

We use [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network/) nuget package in our project.

The source code is very simple:

```
var conection = azureClient.VirtualNetworkGatewayConnections.Get(item.GroupName, item.ConnectionName);
```

This method return all information about VirtualNetworkGatewayConnection and all works fine for non **ExpressRoute** connection.

But if our connection has **ExpressRoute** ConnectionType then ConnectionStatus information is missing.

[image]

How we can extract ConnectionStatus for **ExpressRoute** ConnectionType?

Comment: Could you try to call this REST [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/expressroute/expressroutecircuitconnections/get) with c#,  [How to call the Azure Resource Manager REST API from C#](https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/01/03/how-to-call-the-azure-resource-manager-rest-api-from-c/)